# QT: signal can't be caputured in multithreading

Tags: c++, qt

the relative codes:
there's 3 tread in class:MainWindow

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    TDiceThread     *threadA;       //producer
    TValueThread    *threadValue;   //consumer 1
    TPictureThread  *threadPic;     //consumer 2
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

//there are some slots...

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and the connect of signals and slots:

```
connect(threadValue,&TValueThread::newValue,this, &MainWindow::do_newValue);
connect(threadPic,&TPictureThread::newPicture,this, &MainWindow::do_newPicture);
```

the run() of 3 thread

```
void TDiceThread::run()
{
    seq=0;
    while(1)
    {
        rwLocker.lockForWrite();
        diceValue = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(1,7);
        seq++;
        rwLocker.unlock();
        waiter.wakeAll();
        msleep(500);
    }
}

void TValueThread::run()
{
    while(1)
    {
        rwLocker.lockForRead();
        waiter.wait(&rwLocker);
        emit  newValue(seq,diceValue);
        rwLocker.unlock();
    }
}

void TPictureThread::run()
{
    while(1)
    {
        rwLocker.lockForRead();
        waiter.wait(&rwLocker);
        QString filename=QString::asprintf(":/dice/images/d%d.jpg",diceValue);
        emit  newPicture(filename);
        qDebug()<<"newPicture emitted.";
        rwLocker.unlock();
    }
}
```

but the slots do_newPicture was never invoked.
I used the debugger tool and found the two signals:newPicture and newValue were both emitted.but only the slot do_newValue was invoked and worked perfectly.
the little project zip is here:
[onedrive-check-it-online](https://csueducn-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/8209220125_csu_edu_cn/EdmE2Bv9d_lHslaK1YBpA6QB2lqOprTnwUhpc02LpHjlBQ?e=wMyboA)

Comment: try queued connection `connect(threadValue,&TValueThread::newValue,this, &MainWindow::do_newValue, Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Comment: There's not enough code to answer. Consider putting the effort in to create a [mcve].

Comment: @MarcoF.  I tried it after you suggested it,  didnt work. and i found, even worse, i delete the line```connect(threadValue,&TValueThread::newValue,this, &MainWindow::do_newValue);```   the ```do_newPicture``` wont be invoked still.

Answer (score 1):

The key information that you should have shared is that the debugger tells you exactly this:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QString&'
(Make sure 'QString&' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

And sure enough, you declared your signal with a string reference (`QString&`) parameter:

```
void newPicture(QString &picName);
```

Replace the declaration by one of the 2 versions below:

```
void newPicture(QString picName);
//or
void newPicture(const QString &picName);
```

I recommend the latter.
While you are at it, make it so the slot also uses a const reference:

```
void do_newPicture(const QString& picName);
```